# How to check if the Internet connection (Wifi/Mobile data) is ENABLED?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

How to check if the internet connection is Enabled in Android? Like if the LOCATION SERVICE is disabled we use the technique

```
Location myLocation = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if(myLocation == null){
      Show the AlertDialog.
}else{
do this.
}
```

Like this, how do i check if the Internet connection is Enabled/Disabled.

Comment: may be this link can help u

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null  
    && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()  
    && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {  
    isConnected = true;  
} else {  
    isConnected= false;  
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

For wifi:

```
ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = mgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
```

For Mobile:

```
ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = mgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
```