# Check Internet connectivity - Android

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked a couple of times, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766807/how-to-check-if-the-internet-connection-wifi-mobile-data-is-enabled) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android) but I`m still not getting the desired results by doing something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22766915) when checking for network connectivity

The [isAvailable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isAvailable()) and [isConnected()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected()) methods from [Network Info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) both give a result of **boolean true** when i`m connected to a Wi-Fi router which currently has no internet connectivity .

Here is a screenshot of my phone which can detect the situation in hand.
[image: My phone dose detect this possibility and shows a alert for that]

Is the only way to make sure that the phone/application is actually connected to the internet is actually poll/ping a resource to check for connectivity or handle an exception when trying to make a request?

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27312494/450534. I have used it in a couple of my apps and it works fine. For me at least. ;-). But give it a go anyway.

Comment: @IceMAN thanks for the reply , so refering to my question 

"Is the only way to make sure that the phone/application is actually connected to the internet is actually poll/ping a resource to check for connectivity"

would be true ?

Comment: @Ashar: Yup. That is correct. The solution linked to checks the internet _connectivity_ by pinging the Google DNS 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Levit, Showing two way of checking Network connection / Internet access

**-- Ping a Server**

```
// ICMP 
public boolean isOnline() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);
    }
    catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return false;
}
```

**-- Connect to a Socket on the Internet (advanced)**

```
// TCP/HTTP/DNS (depending on the port, 53=DNS, 80=HTTP, etc.)
public boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        int timeoutMs = 1500;
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);

        sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
        sock.close();

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) { return false; }
}
```

second method very fast (either way), works on all devices, very reliable. But can't run on the UI thread.

[Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out/27312494#27312494)